# How get a data from properties user control on javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Autocomplite.ascx.cs" Inherits="Application.Controls.Autocomplite" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Autocomplite.js"></script>
<img alt="" src="Images/Common/transfer1.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick='SelectInfo(this); return false;' />
```

with properties:

```
public partial class Autocomplite : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            

        }

        private string tableDataSourse;
        public string TableDataSourse
        {
            get { return tableDataSourse; }
            set { tableDataSourse = value; }
        }

        private string positionId;
        public string PositionId
        {
            get { return positionId; }
            set { positionId = value; }
        }
    }
```

I register this control on page and run it like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="apress" TagName="Autocomplite" Src="~/Controls/Autocomplite.ascx" %>
...
<apress:Autocomplite ID="AutoTextBox1" runat="server" TableDataSourse="DataSet" PositionId="NewOrderArticleCode" />
```

On Autocomplite.js (javascript client side) in SelectInfo function I try to get this properties:

```
function SelectInfo(obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
    // expected that obj have this properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should render values of those properties into html elements or attributes, (such as an input element or custom-attributes of an image element). then you can get those values through client-side code.

rendering control-level properties into html code :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Autocomplite.ascx.cs" Inherits="Application.Controls.Autocomplite" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Autocomplite.js"></script>

<img alt="" src="Images/Common/transfer1.png"
style="cursor:pointer;" onclick='SelectInfo(this); return false;'
data-property1='<%= TableDataSourse %>' data-property2='<%= PositionId %>' />
```

access to rendered attribute :

```
function SelectInfo(obj) {
    return $(obj).attr('data-property1') ;
    }
}
```